# Slim remove the last two characters on my Json string

Tags: php, json, slim

I am using the slim framework to create an api which contain a route to get all accounts from my database. I try to return the list of accounts in json but it remove the last two characters which makes it an invalid Json because it is expected to end with }]. I do not know why it is doing that and how to solve it.

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");

   class Account {

         public function getAll(){

                         $db_connection = new Connection();
                         $conn = $db_connection->getConnection();
                         $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from accounts");

                         $numrows = $result->rowCount();
                         if ($numrows > 0) {
                             $rowset = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                          }
                          else {
                              $message['Error'] = 'No Account found';
                              $rowset = $message;     
                          }

                         return $rowset;

           }
  }
```

I am calling the getAll method in my route like

```
 $app->get('/Account/GetAll', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app){
  $application = new Account();
  return $response->withJSON($application->getAll()); 
 });
```

Comment: `$numrows = $result->rowCount();
$rowset = array();
if ($numrows > 0) {
 $rowset[] = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else {
  $message['Error'] = 'No Account found';
  $rowset = $message;     
}

return $rowset;`  check once

Comment: @Anant          I have tried this but it still did not work.

Comment: It look like the problem is based on character limit. When I do select * from accounts limit 13 it return a valid json with 9225 characters. listing all columns one by one with a limit of 14, I get 9587 characters. I minus 2 columns increasing the limit 15 I get 9502 characters. Minus 5 columns I get 9401 characters with limit 17. I got 9506 characters limit 19 minus 7 columns. Each of them if I add 1 to the limit it throw error bad string. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have some whitespace outside of PHP tags. The most likely case is that you have a blank line above a `<?php`. Alternatively, you may have a two blank lines after a `?>`.

Comment: I have checked my codes and there is no blank line before the php tag and none after the php close tag as well. What I realized is that when I put a limit of less than 20 on the query it works fine but if i do not add a limit it remove the last two characters and calling it from another application would throw an error because it is not a valid json.

Comment: Create a really small one-file (& composer.json) example app that shows the problem please.

Comment: Please I do not understand what file you want me to create.